# SQL - how to select all related rows with external (?) conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many, entity-attribute-value

I have three tables:

```
player [id, name]
attribute [id, name]
player_attribute [id, player_id, attribute_id, value]
```

each player can have different attributes, some of them don't have any. Now I need to search for players with certain attributes, e.g. all players that have number 11, and their first name is John. At this moment I also know id's of these attributes, `where` part of my query can look like: `WHERE (attribute.id, attribute.value) in ((5, '11'), (18, 'John'))`

I have to get all players that meets all requested attributes.

The problem is I don't know how the whole query have to look like? I tried joins, nested selects, grouping by but I'm not able to make it work. I'm always getting too much, or not enough rows.

Can you help me please?

**EDIT**
Thanks to aranid I've found a solution:

```
select player_id from (
    select * from player_attribute where (attribute.id, attribute.value) in ((5, '11'), (18, 'John'))) 
group by player_id
having count(*) = 2
```

so, the keyword was `having by` used properly :)
Is there any way to transform above query into `JOIN` statement?

Comment: This kind of question recurs reasonably often, you may find additional inspiration in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102362/sql-how-do-i-make-a-selection-based-on-categories for example.

Comment: thanks araqnid! I've found some hints there, I edit my question to include an answer

Comment: I added the `eav` tag but I had to cannibalize the `select` tag you used, since there's a limit of five tags.  I thought `select` was superfluous after `sql` and `query`.

Answer (score 2):

Hope I got your question right. This should return all `player_id`s which have an attribute `(5, '11')` and another one with `(18, 'John')`:

```
Select a1.player_id
From player_attribute a1
Join player_attribute a2 On ( a2.player_id = a1.player_id )
Where a1.attribute_id = 5 And a1.value = '11'
  And a2.attribute_id = 18 And a1.value = 'John'
```

---

Any particular reason for not storing these attributes in the `player` table?

```
player (id, first_name, last_name, player_number, ...)
```

This would make such queries much easier

```
Select id
From player
Where first_name = 'John' And player_number = 11
```

Comment: well, that works, but the problem is, what if I need to search for 3 attributes, or 10, or more? also, the attributes aren't stored in player table, because they are defined by end-user and I don't know how many and what kind of attributes will be needed

Answer (score 2):

You're using the Entity-Attribute-Value design, and this is just awkward for any relational database.

You'd probably be happier using one of the new non-relational databases such as [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) or [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/).  These are *document-oriented databases*, designed for exactly the scenario you have, where users can define their own attributes and you don't know the attributes at the time you design the database.

Comment: thanks for your advice. the tables I used here are just an example, the project I'm working on is quite big at the moment and I need those attributes in a some small part of it, so moving to another DB isn't possible. thanks anyway!

Comment: Using an HSTORE, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/hstore.html , in Postgres provides many of the same schemaless benefits as non-relational databases.